# Why does the ring element get absorbed here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> Suppose $M$ is finitely generated over $R$ that is a PID. Let $x \in M$, $\ann(x) = (a)$, $p\in R$ be irreducible. Then

> 1. If $p|a$ then $Rx/pRx \approx R/(p)$
> 2. If $p \not| a$, then $pRx = Rx.$

The proof goes like this in the textbook

1. Let $\phi(r) = rx$, then $\ker \phi = (a)$. Since $p|a$, then $(p)$ under $\phi$ is $pRx$, so $(p)/(a) = pRx$ and $R/(a) = Rx$, so $R/(p) = Rx/pRx$.

Okay so elements in $(p)$ are $pd$, and under $\phi$ this is $pdx \in pRx$ because $d$ is arbitrary.

2. If $p \not|a$ then $gcd(p,a)=1$ so there exists $s,t$ such that $sp + ta = 1$. Therefore $rx = 1rx = psrx + tart = psrx \implies Rx = pRx$.

Now I don't get that conclusion. Since $rx = psrx$ isn't $psrx \in psRx$? $s$ here isn't arbitrary like above.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: And what does the equality  $Rx/pRx = R/(p)$ mean? The LHS and RHS are completely different sets.

Comment: $R$ is a PID and $M$ is over R. I will add this sorry

Comment: @JCAA it is isomorphism sorry

Comment: @JCAA , what is that \ann formatting in the question ? What was it actually for ?

Comment: @Spectre: I am not the OP. I am sure "ann" means the annihilator  (that is, $ann(X)=\{a\in R\mid ax=0 \forall x\in X\}$)

Answer (score 0):

Since s and r are both in R, we have sr is in R, so psrx is in pRx

Comment: Then what is the point of $a$? Why not just say that $rx \in pRx$ because $p$ is also an element of $R$?